# CUDA, Using 2D and 3D Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, cuda

There are a lot of questions online about allocating, copying, indexing, etc 2d and 3d arrays on CUDA. I'm getting a lot of conflicting answers so I'm attempting to compile past questions to see if I can ask the right ones.

First link: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/392370/how-to-cudamalloc-two-dimensional-array-/

Problem: Allocating a 2d array of pointers

User solution: use mallocPitch

"Correct" inefficient solution: Use malloc and memcpy in a for loop for each row (Absurd overhead)

"More correct" solution: Squash it into a 1d array "professional opinion," one comment saying no one with an eye on performance uses 2d pointer structures on the gpu

Second link: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/413905/passing-a-multidimensional-array-to-kernel-how-to-allocate-space-in-host-and-pass-to-device-/

Problem: Allocating space on host and passing it to device

Sub link: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/398305/cuda-programming-and-performance/dynamically-allocate-array-of-structs/

Sub link solution: Coding pointer based structures on the GPU is a bad experience and highly inefficient, squash it into a 1d array.

Third link: [Allocate 2D Array on Device Memory in CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047369/allocate-2d-array-on-device-memory-in-cuda)

Problem: Allocating and transferring 2d arrays

User solution: use mallocPitch

Other solution: flatten it

Fourth link: [How to use 2D Arrays in CUDA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029920/how-to-use-2d-arrays-in-cuda)

Problem: Allocate and traverse 2d arrays

Submitted solution: Does not show allocation

Other solution: squash it

There are a lot of other sources mostly saying the same thing but in multiple instances I see warnings about pointer structures on the GPU.

Many people claim the proper way to allocate an array of pointers is with a call to malloc and memcpy for each row yet the functions mallocPitch and memcpy2D exist. Are these functions somehow less efficient? Why wouldn't this be the default answer?

The other 'correct' answer for 2d arrays is to squash them into one array. Should I just get used to this as a fact of life? I'm very persnickety about my code and it feels inelegant to me.

Another solution I was considering was to max a matrix class that uses a 1d pointer array but I can't find a way to implement the double bracket operator.

Also according to this link: [Copy an object to device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024087/copy-an-object-to-device)

and the sub link answer: [cudaMemcpy segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431365/cudamemcpy-segmentation-fault/15435592#15435592)

This gets a little iffy.

The classes I want to use CUDA with all have 2/3d arrays and wouldn't there be a lot of overhead in converting those to 1d arrays for CUDA?

I know I've asked a lot but in summary should I get used to squashed arrays as a fact of life or can I use the 2d allocate and copy functions without getting bad overhead like in the solution where alloc and cpy are called in a for loop?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since your question compiles a list of other questions, I'll answer by compiling a list of other answers.

**cudaMallocPitch/cudaMemcpy2D:**

First, the cuda runtime API functions like `cudaMallocPitch` and `cudaMemcpy2D` do not actually involve either double-pointer allocations or 2D (doubly-subscripted) arrays.  This is easy to confirm simply by looking at [the documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g3a58270f6775efe56c65ac47843e7cee), and noting the types of parameters in the function prototypes.  The `src` and `dst` parameters are single-pointer parameters.  They could not be doubly-subscripted, or doubly dereferenced.  For additional example usage, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951111/cudamemcpy2d-setting-values-to-0/17951471#17951471) is one of many questions on this.  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002361/bad-data-coming-from-cudamemcpy2d/26003418#26003418) is a fully worked example usage. Another example covering various concepts associated with `cudaMallocPitch`/`cudaMemcpy2d` usage is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905899/cuda-2d-array-indexing-giving-unexpected-results/16906291#16906291). Instead the correct way to think about these is that they work with *pitched* allocations.  Also, you cannot use `cudaMemcpy2D` to transfer data when the underlying allocation has been created using a set of `malloc` (or `new`, or similar) operations in a loop.  That sort of host data allocation construction is particularly ill-suited to working with the data on the device.

**general, dynamically allocated 2D case:**

If you wish to learn how to use a dynamically allocated 2D array in a CUDA kernel (meaning you can use doubly-subscripted access, e.g. `data[x][y]`), then the [`cuda` tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cuda/info) contains the "canonical" question for this, it is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137218/how-can-i-add-up-two-2d-pitched-arrays-using-nested-for-loops).   The answer given by talonmies there includes the proper mechanics, as well as appropriate caveats:

- there is additional, non-trivial complexity
- the access will generally be less efficient than 1D access, because data access requires dereferencing 2 pointers, instead of 1.

(note that allocating an array of objects, where the object(s) has an embedded pointer to a dynamic allocation, is essentially the same as the 2D array concept, and [the example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16024087/copy-an-object-to-device) you linked in your question is a reasonable demonstration for that)

Also, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68037236/how-do-i-convert-a-stdvectorthrustdevice-vectorint-to-int) is a thrust method for building a general dynamically allocated 2D array.

**flattening:**

If you think you must use the general 2D method, then go ahead, it's not  impossible (although sometimes [people struggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082991/memory-allocation-on-gpu-for-dynamic-array-of-structs) with the process!)  However, due to the added complexity and reduced efficiency, the canonical "advice" here is to "flatten" your storage method, and use "simulated" 2D access.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16599501/cudamemcpy-function-usage/16616738#16616738) is one of many examples of questions/answers discussing "flattening".

**general, dynamically allocated 3D case:**

As we extend this to 3 (or higher!) dimensions, the general case becomes overly complex to handle, IMO.  The additional complexity should strongly motivate us to seek alternatives.  The triply-subscripted general case involves 3 pointer accesses before the data is actually retrieved, so even less efficient.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924155/sending-3d-array-to-cuda-kernel/12925014#12925014) is a fully worked example (2nd code example).

**special case: array width known at compile time:**

Note that it should be considered a *special case* when the array dimension(s) (the *width*, in the case of a 2D array, or 2 of the 3 dimensions for a 3D array) is known at compile-time.  In this case, with an appropriate auxiliary type definition, we can "instruct" the compiler how the indexing should be computed, and in this case we can use doubly-subscripted access with considerably less complexity than the general case, *and* there is no loss of efficiency due to pointer-chasing.  Only one pointer need be dereferenced to retrieve the data (regardless of array dimensionality, if n-1 dimensions are known at compile time for a n-dimensional array).  The first code example in the already-mentioned answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924155/sending-3d-array-to-cuda-kernel/12925014#12925014) (first code example) gives a fully worked example of that in the 3D case, and the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41050300/how-do-i-allocate-memory-and-copy-2d-arrays-between-cpu-gpu-in-cuda-without-fl/41053215#41053215) gives a 2D example of this special case.

**doubly-subscripted host code, singly-subscripted device code:**

Finally another methodology option allows us to easily mix 2D (doubly-subscripted) access in *host code* while using only 1D (singly-subscripted, perhaps with "simulated 2D" access) in *device code*.  A worked example of that is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24659276/cuda-allocating-1d-device-memory-to-copy-2d-pointer-to-pointer-host-array-to-an/24660223#24660223).  By organizing the underlying allocation as a contiguous allocation, then building the pointer "tree", we can enable doubly-subscripted access on the host, and still easily pass the flat allocation to the device.  Although the example does not show it, it would be possible to extend this method to create a doubly-subscripted access system on the device based off a flat allocation and a manually-created pointer "tree", however this would have approximately the same issues as the 2D general dynamically allocated method given above: it would involve double-pointer (double-dereference) access, so less efficient, and there is some complexity associated with building the pointer "tree", for use in device code (e.g. it would necessitate an additional `cudaMemcpy` operation, probably).

From the above methods, you'll need to choose one that fits your appetite and needs.  There is not one single recommendation that fits every possible case.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75850905/is-passing-and-operating-on-an-array-with-more-than-one-dimension-in-cuda-imposs/75851184#75851184) goes into a finer-grained explanation of the difference between two categories of implementation/methods.

Arrays of objects with nested pointers conceptually is similar to handling 2D arrays.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78123170/1695960) is a worked example showing the general 2D dynamic allocation method. Flattening and other methods are also possible.