# CUDA + count int element occurrences using C

Tags: c, cuda, gpu, distributed-computing

On the host side I'm reading in a 128 x 128 integer array with random values between 0-31. I have an Occurrences array that stores the values 0-31 and then on the device I am trying to execute a kernel that loops through the values in the 128 x 128 array and then counts the number of times 0-31 appears.

I am having issues with how to split up the blocks/threads in CUDA and how to get the kernel to provide communication back to the host and print out the number of occurrences of every element.This is my first time using CUDA and I would appreciate any constructive advice! Here is my code so far:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cuda.h>


#define MAXR 16
#define MAXC 16
#define N 256
__global__ void count(int *arrayONE_d, int *occurrences_d, int *occurrences_final_d) {

    int count = 0;
    //provide unique thread ID
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    int k;
    //for(k=0; k < 32;k++) {
    //  occurrences_d[k]=k;
//  }


    if(idx < N) {
        //for(k=0; k < MAXR*MAXC; k++) {
    for(int j=0; j<32; j++) {
            count =0;
        if(arrayONE_d[idx]==occurrences_d[j]){

            count+=1;
            occurrences_final_d[j] =count;
        }
        else {}


    }
    }
    //occurrences_final_d[0] = 77;
    }
}


int main(void) {



    //const int N = MAXR*MAXC;

    int arr1_h[MAXR][MAXC];
    //int *occurrences_h[0][32];
    //creating arrays for the device (GPU)
    //int *arr1_d;
    int occurrences_h[32];
    int *occurrences_d;

    int *occurrences_final_h[32] = {0};
    int *occurrences_final_d;

    int *arrayONE_h[256] = {0};
    int *arrayONE_d;

    int i, j;

    // allocating memory for the arrays on the device
    cudaMalloc( (void**) &arrayONE_d, MAXR*MAXC*sizeof(int)); // change to 16384 when using 128x128
    cudaMalloc( (void**) &occurrences_d,  32* sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc( (void**) &occurrences_final_d, 32*sizeof(int));

    /*
    for(i=0; i < 32; i++) {

        occurrences_h[i] = i;

    }
/*
 *
 */
    //Reading in matrix from .txt file and storing it in arr1 on the host (CPU)
    FILE *fp;
    fp =fopen("arrays16.txt","r");

     // this loop takes the information from .txt file and puts it into arr1 matrix
    for(i=0;i<MAXR;i++) {


        for(j=0;j<MAXC;j++)
        {
            fscanf(fp,"%d\t", &arr1_h[i][j]);
        }

    }

    for(i=0;i<MAXR;i++) {
        printf("\n");

        for(j=0;j<MAXC;j++) {
            //printf("d\t", arr1_h[i][j]);
        }

        printf("\n\n");
    }


    int x,y;
    int z=0;
// this loop flattens the 2d array and makes it a 1d array of length MAXR*MAXC
    for(x=0;x<MAXR;x++)
    {
        for(y=0;y<MAXC;y++)
        {
            //  printf("**%d   ",arr1_h[x][y]);

            arrayONE_h[z]= &arr1_h[x][y];
            z++;

        }
    }


    for(x=0; x < 256; x++) {
        printf("%d\n", *arrayONE_h[x]);
        //return 0;

    }

    int length = sizeof(arrayONE_h)/sizeof(arrayONE_h[0]);

    printf("\n\n");
    printf("**LENGTH = %d", length);

    // copying the arrays/memory from the host to the device (GPU)
    cudaMemcpy(arrayONE_d, &arrayONE_h, MAXR*MAXC*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(occurrences_d, &occurrences_h, 32*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(occurrences_final_d, &occurrences_final_h, 32*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // how many blocks we will allocate
    //dim3 DimGrid();
    //how many threads per block we will allocate
    dim3 DimBlock(256);

    //kernel launch against the GPU
    count<<<1, DimBlock>>>(arrayONE_d,occurrences_d,occurrences_final_d);

    //copy the arrays post-computation from the device back to the host (CPU)
    cudaMemcpy(&occurrences_final_h, occurrences_final_d, 32*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(&occurrences_h, occurrences_d, 32*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // some error checking - run this with cuda-memcheck when executing your code
    cudaError_t errSync  = cudaGetLastError();
    cudaError_t errAsync = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (errSync != cudaSuccess)
        printf("Sync kernel error: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(errSync));
    if (errAsync != cudaSuccess)
        printf("Async kernel error: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(errAsync));

    //free up the memory of the device arrays
    cudaFree(arrayONE_d);
    cudaFree(occurrences_d);
    cudaFree(occurrences_final_d);

    //print out the number of occurrences of each 0-31 value
    for(i=0;i<32;i++) {
        printf("\n");

        printf("%d\n",occurrences_final_h[i]);

    }

}
```

Comment: The algorithm you are working on usually goes by the name **histogram**.  There are many available library solutions to do this. Furthermore, googling "cuda histogram" might give you some useful reading.   In addition, handling a 2D array in CUDA usually requires some extra effort, and if you're a beginner it may be a lot easier if you flatten your array.  A naive CUDA histogram can be done using atomics with a trivially simple kernel that requires no loops at all.  You might want to start with that just to get a baseline established.

Comment: Any time you are having trouble with a CUDA code, I recommend using [proper CUDA error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589) and running your code with `cuda-memcheck`, **before** asking others for help.  You have some CUDA error checking in your code now, but its not quite complete.  If you include the actual output from these when you run your program, it will be useful for others trying to help you, even if you don't understand the output yourself.  Providing a proper [mcve] includes providing the actual output as well as expected output from your program.

Comment: I have run the executable with cuda-memcheck and the main error I receive is that the thread misalignment. I have tried numerous things to fix this but so far to no avail. any suggestions on why this is happening?

Comment: I have seen examples that use histogram, but in general for this course we have been asked to keep it as close to our serial code as possible (hence using the loops)

Comment: When I run your code, I get a seg fault.  A seg fault is a problem that always pertains to host code, not GPU code.  Due to the seg fault I get no output from `cuda-memcheck`.  If you're getting something else, my guess is that you are not running the code you have posted in the question.  I've already suggested that your handling of 2D arrays is broken, and I believe the seg fault is arising due to that.  I suggest you start by flattening your arrays.  If not, then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45643682) provides a summary of proper methods for handling 2D arrays in CUDA.

Comment: interesting. the last time i ran it was yesterday and may have made some changes so thats good to know. i was about to run it so thank you. the seg fault is interesting too since when i run this serially it works just fine.

Comment: flattening the array seems like a good idea though and useful advice.

Comment: So I can get the communication between device/host working okay but I am trying to assign for a 16 x 16 array --> 1 block and 256 threads per block after flattening the 2d array into a 1d array. I want every thread to work on one element of the [256] and check through an occurrences array [32] which has values 0-31 and count the number of times. But I can't seem to get the kernel to compute this correctly. any advice? I can post the kernel code if that would be helpful.

Comment: Update/edit your question with the complete code that you are working on that does what you described.  Note that since every thread is potentially accessing the same element in the occurrences array[32] (right?) you will need some method to prevent the threads from stepping on each other as they read and write to it.  As already mentioned, atomics is one approach.  Your ordinary loop code will not take care of this issue.

Comment: thank you for your response. I have edited the code with the current status. My thought process was to run the threads against every element in the [256] array and have each of those elements loop through until they match one of the values in occurrences[32] array and then count. But please tell me if you think this is the wrong way to think about it. Bear in mind, in my course we haven't learn atomics so i dont know if i should be incorporating it.thank you again.

Comment: I still get a seg fault with your code that you have posted now.  You are certainly doing incorrect things with arrays of pointers, and it seems like you may be struggling with understanding of pointers in C/C++.

Comment: ah.  Your code requires an input file.  Good programming practice says that if `fopen` return an error, you don't ignore it.

Comment: Yes, definitely new to C. I've come from a Matlab/Java background. Appreciate your patience. When I run it on my universities server using 4 cores, I actually print out the occurrences_final_h array. I set the [0] element on it on the kernel just to ensure the communication is occurring. It is, when I run it it prints out the first element of the array followed by all zeros for the rest of the elements.

Comment: yes sorry I should have mentioned that. the arr1 is loading in a random matrix from a .txt file. It was a requirement of the assignment.

Comment: I have fixed some of the pointer issues I believe having researching it more after your comment. I am still printing out the occurences_final_h array with all zeros which is obviously wrong.

Comment: Robert - is there any advice you can give or an area I need to focus on to make this work properly? I have since made it so that each thread operates on one element of the occurrences array (0-31 values, size = 32) and checks and counts every time it finds a match in the 1*256 array (flattened 128 x 128 array). Kind regards.

Comment: That's  a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, your understanding of pointers is flawed.  I've made changes at many places in your code to address this.  I've marked most of them with the comment `// mod` but I may have missed some.

In addition, your kernel simply cannot keep track of elements when multiple threads can update the same location.  One way to sort this out is to use atomics (which I've demonstrated.)  There are various other approaches such as parallel reduction, but none of these are trivial changes to the kernel.  In addition, your kernel logic was broken in a few ways.

What follows then is the smallest number of modifications I could make to your code to get something sensible.  There are a few compile switches you can use to explore different kernel behavior:

- no switch  - close to your kernel, but it will not work correctly
- `-DUSE_ATOMICS` will demonstrate a modification to your kernel to get it to count correctly.
- `-DUSE_ALT_KERNEL` explores a different approach to kernel logic: assign one thread per histogram bin, and have each thread traverse the entire array, keeping track of elements that belong to that bin.  Since only one thread is writing to each bin result, there is no need for atomics.  However we can only have as many threads (with this trivial realization) as there are bins.  Without too much difficulty this method could probably be extended to one warp per bin, [using warp shuffle to do a final warp-level reduction](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#warp-examples-reduction) before having one thread write the final results to the bin. This would improve memory access efficiency somewhat. However this will also introduce complexity into the kernel that you've probably not learned yet.

Here is the code:

```
$ cat t316.cu
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cuda.h>


#define MAXR 16
#define MAXC 16
#define BINS 32
#define N (MAXR*MAXC)
__global__ void count(int *arrayONE_d, int *occurrences_d, int *occurrences_final_d) {

    //provide unique thread ID
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
#ifndef USE_ALT_KERNEL
    if(idx < N) {
        //for(k=0; k < MAXR*MAXC; k++) {
    for(int j=0; j<32; j++) {
        if(arrayONE_d[idx]==occurrences_d[j]){
#ifndef USE_ATOMICS
            occurrences_final_d[j]++;
#else
         atomicAdd(occurrences_final_d+j, 1);
#endif

        }
        else {}


    }
    }
#else
   // use one thread per histo bin
   if (idx < BINS){
     int count = 0;
     int myval = occurrences_d[idx];
     for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) if (arrayONE_d[i] == myval) count++;
     occurrences_final_d[idx] = count;
     }

#endif
    }


int main(void) {



    //const int N = MAXR*MAXC;

    int arr1_h[MAXR][MAXC];
    //int *occurrences_h[0][32];
    //creating arrays for the device (GPU)
    //int *arr1_d;
    int occurrences_h[32]; // mod
    int *occurrences_d;

    int occurrences_final_h[32] = {0};  // mod
    int *occurrences_final_d;

    int arrayONE_h[256] = {0};  // mod
    int *arrayONE_d;

    int i, j;

    // allocating memory for the arrays on the device
    cudaMalloc( (void**) &arrayONE_d, MAXR*MAXC*sizeof(int)); // change to 16384 when using 128x128
    cudaMalloc( (void**) &occurrences_d,  32* sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc( (void**) &occurrences_final_d, 32*sizeof(int));

    /*
    for(i=0; i < 32; i++) {

        occurrences_h[i] = i;

    }
 */
    //Reading in matrix from .txt file and storing it in arr1 on the host (CPU)

//    FILE *fp;
//    fp =fopen("arrays16.txt","r");

     // this loop takes the information from .txt file and puts it into arr1 matrix
    for(i=0;i<MAXR;i++) {


        for(j=0;j<MAXC;j++)
        {
//            fscanf(fp,"%d\t", &arr1_h[i][j]);
              arr1_h[i][j] = j;  // mod
        }

    }

    for(i=0;i<MAXR;i++) {

        for(j=0;j<MAXC;j++) {
            //printf("d\t", arr1_h[i][j]);
        }

    }


    int x,y;
    int z=0;
// this loop flattens the 2d array and makes it a 1d array of length MAXR*MAXC
    for(x=0;x<MAXR;x++)
    {
        for(y=0;y<MAXC;y++)
        {
            //  printf("**%d   ",arr1_h[x][y]);

            arrayONE_h[z]= arr1_h[x][y];  // mod
            z++;

        }
    }


    for(x=0; x < 256; x++) {
//        printf("%d\n", arrayONE_h[x]);  // mod
        //return 0;

    }

    int length = sizeof(arrayONE_h)/sizeof(arrayONE_h[0]);

    printf("**LENGTH = %d\n", length);

    // copying the arrays/memory from the host to the device (GPU)
    cudaMemcpy(arrayONE_d, arrayONE_h, MAXR*MAXC*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);  //mod
    cudaMemcpy(occurrences_d, occurrences_h, 32*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);   // mod
    cudaMemcpy(occurrences_final_d, occurrences_final_h, 32*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); // mod

    // how many blocks we will allocate
    //dim3 DimGrid();
    //how many threads per block we will allocate
#ifndef USE_ALT_KERNEL
    dim3 DimBlock(N);
#else
    dim3 DimBlock(BINS);
#endif
    //kernel launch against the GPU
    count<<<1, DimBlock>>>(arrayONE_d,occurrences_d,occurrences_final_d);

    //copy the arrays post-computation from the device back to the host (CPU)
    cudaMemcpy(occurrences_final_h, occurrences_final_d, 32*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost); // mod
    cudaMemcpy(occurrences_h, occurrences_d, 32*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);  // mod

    // some error checking - run this with cuda-memcheck when executing your code
    cudaError_t errSync  = cudaGetLastError();
    cudaError_t errAsync = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (errSync != cudaSuccess)
        printf("Sync kernel error: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(errSync));
    if (errAsync != cudaSuccess)
        printf("Async kernel error: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(errAsync));

    //free up the memory of the device arrays
    cudaFree(arrayONE_d);
    cudaFree(occurrences_d);
    cudaFree(occurrences_final_d);

    //print out the number of occurrences of each 0-31 value
    for(i=0;i<32;i++) {
        printf("%d ",occurrences_final_h[i]);

    }
    printf("\n");
}
$ nvcc -o t316 t316.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t316
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
**LENGTH = 256
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$ nvcc -o t316 t316.cu -DUSE_ATOMICS
$ ./t316
**LENGTH = 256
16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16
$ nvcc -o t316 t316.cu -DUSE_ALT_KERNEL
$ cuda-memcheck ./t316
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
**LENGTH = 256
16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16 16
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

In the above output we see that the base kernel produces incorrect results.  The atomics kernel and the alternate kernel produce correct results

(Your code has been modified to use synthesized data so that it does not need to open a file.)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. taught me a lot honestly so that was the best part. modified it some to make it work for my implementation.