# C++ Cuda performance for double pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, cuda

I finally succeded in saving in memory a double pointer in order to use it in cuda.(The code below), but i see that is less performent than if i would flatten the matrix,which is not that great.

Some suggestions to save some time/memory?

I really want to use dynamic 2d array.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdio>

__global__ void fct(int **dev_c)
{
    int y = threadIdx.x;
    int x = threadIdx.y;
    dev_c[y][x] = 3;
}

int main(void)
{
    //Output Array
    int **cc = new int*[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)cc[i] = new int[2];
    //Host Array
    int ** h_c = (int **)malloc(2 * sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        cudaMalloc((void**)&h_c[i], 2 * sizeof(int));
    }
    //Devie array
    int ** d_c;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_c, 2 * sizeof(int *));
    cudaMemcpy(d_c, h_c, 2 * sizeof(int *), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);


    dim3 d(2, 2);
    fct << <1, d >> > (d_c);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        cudaMemcpy(cc[i], h_c[i], 2 * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            printf("(%d,%d):%d\n", i, j, cc[i][j]);
        }
    }
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
    delete[] h_c;
    delete[] d_c;
}
```

Comment: If you know the width of your 2D matrix at compile time, it's possible to use doubly-subscripted access (even in device code) while still maintaining the performance benefits of indexed vs. double-pointer access.  This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45643682/cuda-using-2d-and-3d-arrays/45644824#45644824) discusses various methods including the known-width approach.  If you do not know the width of your 2D matrix at compile time, I'm not aware of any method to do doubly-subscripted access without 2 pointer dereferences per access.

Comment: Thank you!
I will keep in mind this but sadly for this project i need that array to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may actually want to use flattened matrix with some pointer tricks:

```
int main() {
    const int size = 10;

    auto arr = new int*[size];
    arr[0] = new int[size * size];
    for(int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        arr[i] = arr[0] + (i * size);
    }
}
```

This way, you can still access the matrix with `arr[x][y]` syntax, but the actual memory is contiguous (which is not only faster to allocate*, but faster to access, given cache pre-fetching memory around the one you desire to use).

*<sub>It is faster to allocate `size * size` memory once, rather than allocating `size` times `size` elements.</sub>

Side note: using `delete[]` on a `malloc`ed memory is *undefined behaviour*. Don't mix `new`/`new[]` + `delete`/`delete[]` with `malloc` + `free`.

Comment: Thank you!

Still, if i wanna save that arr in cuda memory i can do it like a simple vector?Or i have to alloc every row?

Comment: @VladConstantinescu What do you mean by `simple vector`?

Comment: I mean , 1d array ( int *a = new int[size])

Comment: You can pass this matrix as a 1d array simply by passing `*arr` (or `arr[0]`), if that's what you are asking. It's still a little unclear. Do you want to pass the whole matrix as a single 1d array? Or you want to pass single rows as 1d arrays?

Comment: i want to pass to the kernel function(fct) the whole 2d matrix.

There is a way that i will still  be able to use the syntax matrix[i][j] inside the function ?

Comment: sorry for lack of details, i misunderstood your answer. but now it's all clear:).

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, if you pass `arr` (not `arr[0]`), you will be able to use the `matrix[x][y]` syntax but that requires the function to accept `int**` argument.