# NVCC error when compiling function with 2D array argument

Tags: c, cuda, nvcc

I'm trying to pass a 2D array to a C function in a CUDA code, and `nvcc` won't compile it, but `gcc` works fine. Here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void f(int row, int col, int[row][col]) {
    printf("LOL\n");
}

int main(void) {
    int mat[2][3];
    f(2, 3, mat);
}
```

If I put this code in `test.c` and run `gcc test.c`, it works as expected.

If I put this code in `test.cu` and run `nvcc test.cu`, it throws the following error:

```
test.cu(3): error: a parameter is not allowed
```

Why is it not working with `nvcc` ? It it's not supported, what's the best way to give a 2D array as parameter in CUDA ? A pointer to the first element of the first row ?

Thanks in advance for help on this.

Comment: When you compile with nvcc, a C++ compiler is used for that code.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45643682/cuda-using-2d-and-3d-arrays/45644824#45644824) covers a variety of methods to handle 2D arrays in CUDA.  If you know the width of your 2D array at compile time, then the methods described there with known width are good choices.  They allow you to express 2D subscripting while still having efficient single-pointer access.  Otherwise, flattening is probably the best approach for performance ("A pointer to the first element of the first row", assuming the underlying allocation is contiguous across rows.)

Answer (score 1):

For C99 compatible Compiler this method works, otherwise you should use pointer with cast, like that:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void f(int row, int col, int *a) {
    printf("LOL\n");
}

int main(void) {
    int mat[2][3];
    f(2, 3, (int*)mat);
}
```

Comment: Casts are best avoided.  To do so here without a cast, use `f(2, 3, mat[0]);`.

Comment: `f(int row, int col, int *a)`  lacks showing how to access the data in `a` which differs from the convenient `a[r][c]`.