# Copy double pointer array into CUDA memory using cudaMalloc

Tags: c, cuda

I'm attempting to copy a 2d double pointer array from the system memory to my GPU memory using cudaMalloc. I tried using the solution to [this question](https://coderedirect.com/questions/467957/copying-2d-arrays-to-gpu-of-known-variable-width) however a) it doesn't appear to be working and b) the solution was designed for jagged arrays where each row has a variable width, which results in a more inefficient solution (o(n) vs the theoretically possible o(1) via a single malloc call.

This program is designed to copy the contents of **src to **dst and return the destination array back to system memory. Could someone point out why this doesn't work? I'm a n00b at c and cuda so appreciate the help.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

__global__
void copy(double **src, double **dst,  int width, int height)

{
   for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            dst[i][j] = src[i][j];
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int width = 3;
    int height = 5;


    double **src_ptr;
    double **cuda_src;

    double **dst_ptr;
    double **cuda_dst;


    src_ptr = (double **)malloc(width * sizeof(double*));
    dst_ptr = (double **)malloc(width * sizeof(double*));

    cudaMalloc(cuda_src, width * sizeof(double*));
    cudaMalloc(cuda_dst, width * sizeof(double*));


    for(int i = 0; i<width;i++){
        src_ptr[i] = (double *)malloc(height * sizeof *src_ptr[i]);
        dst_ptr[i] = (double *)malloc(height * sizeof *dst_ptr[i]);


        cudaMalloc((void ** ) &cuda_src[i], height * sizeof(double));
        cudaMalloc((void ** ) &cuda_dst[i], height * sizeof(double));

        for(int j=0;j<height;j++){
            src_ptr[i][j] = (double)(rand() % 1000) / 1000;
            dst_ptr[i][j] = 0.;

        }
    }
    cudaMemcpy(cuda_src, src_ptr, width * sizeof(double*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    copy<<<1,1>>>(cuda_src, cuda_dst, width, height);

    cudaMemcpy(dst_ptr, cuda_dst, width * sizeof(double*), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

   printf("Source: \n");
   for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            printf("%f ", src_ptr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n\nDest:\n");
   for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            printf("%f ", dst_ptr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


}
```

Expected output:

```
Source: 
0.383000 0.886000 0.777000 0.915000 0.793000 
0.335000 0.386000 0.492000 0.649000 0.421000 
0.362000 0.027000 0.690000 0.059000 0.763000 


Dest:
0.383000 0.886000 0.777000 0.915000 0.793000 
0.335000 0.386000 0.492000 0.649000 0.421000 
0.362000 0.027000 0.690000 0.059000 0.763000
```

Actual output:

```
Source: 
0.383000 0.886000 0.777000 0.915000 0.793000 
0.335000 0.386000 0.492000 0.649000 0.421000 
0.362000 0.027000 0.690000 0.059000 0.763000 


Dest:
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

Comment: What you're trying to do is a deep copy.  This is covered in many questions already here on the `cuda` tag, and is a frequently asked question.  There are multiple reasons why your attempt won't work.  At a high level, 2 of them are that *every* `cudaMalloc` operation will require a corresponding `cudaMemcpy` operation, and you cannot ask `cudaMalloc` to update a pointer that is already in device memory.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45643682/cuda-using-2d-and-3d-arrays) provides a summary with example links of how a 2D copy like this might be realized.

Comment: Thanks @RobertCrovella. I'll take a look at that thread and see if there's anything there that helps.